# How to know the profile path programmatically in the executing chrome browse

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I searched Google API Reference or stackoverflow, but I couldn't find a way to get the profile path for the current user using a file or API. Is there any official way?

for eaxmple.

1. current a profile name of executing chrome browser is "chaed"
2. And chaed's profile is created here.
   C:\Users<user>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data
3. Maybe folder of profile name is Profile 2, Profile 3... But It dosen't know exactly what
   folder for the chaed profile is